# Nans Being Generated after training a neural network for sometime using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I am facing this problem since a few days. I don't know where I am making a mistake. My code is lengthy and could not reproduce everything here

Here are the results in first case:

```
Accuracy: 0.1071 Error: 1.45003
Accuracy: 0.5149 Error: 0.259084
Accuracy: 0.7199 Error: 0.197301
Accuracy: 0.7934 Error: 0.138881
Accuracy: 0.8137 Error: 0.136115
Accuracy: 0.8501 Error: 0.15382
Accuracy: 0.8642 Error: 0.100813
Accuracy: 0.8761 Error: 0.0882854
Accuracy: 0.882 Error: 0.0874575
Accuracy: 0.8861 Error: 0.0629579
Accuracy: 0.8912 Error: 0.101606
Accuracy: 0.8939 Error: 0.0744626
Accuracy: 0.8975 Error: 0.0775732
Accuracy: 0.8957 Error: 0.0909776
Accuracy: 0.9002 Error: 0.0799101
Accuracy: 0.9034 Error: 0.0621196
Accuracy: 0.9004 Error: 0.0752576
Accuracy: 0.9068 Error: 0.0531508
Accuracy: 0.905 Error: 0.0699344
Accuracy: 0.8941 Error: nan
Accuracy: 0.893 Error: nan
Accuracy: 0.893 Error: nan
```

I have tried various things but failed to figure out where I am making a mistake.

1) Change cross-entropy calculations to different things

```
self._error = -tf.reduce_sum(y*pred+ 1e-9))
self._error = -tf.reduce_sum(y*pred)
self._error = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=pred, labels=y))
self._error = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y * tf.log(pred+1e-8),reduction_indices=1))

out = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = pred, labels=y)
self._error= tf.reduce_mean(out)
```

I have tried all the optimizers 
- sgd
- adam
- adagrad
- rmsprop

I have used both default optimizers provided by tensorflow and manually applied different parameters. To point I have even checked with learning rates as small as 0.00001

**Bias:**
I have tried both 1.0 and 0.0

**Weights:**
Initialized with tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1, dtype = tf.float32)

**Network:**
FC784 - FC256 - FC128 - FC10
I have tried different variants of it also.

**Activation Function:**
- Relu
- Tanh
- leaky relu tf.maximum(input, 0.1*input)

**Data:**
MNIST dataset normalized by dividing it with 255. The dataset is from Keras.

I know this question is asked in various stackoverflow question and I have tried all the methods suggested der and to my knowledge none of them helped me.

Comment: Sometime devices give `None` answer for some reason, it's normal but how to you handle this ?  NAN equal to "don't prepared yet", "resource is busy", "value is overflowed" etc.  All resource access got  `delay`, like: you got delay `1/CPU_CLOCK` on a computer. Check your device capabilities... **0/None = NAN**

Comment: I have run the code in 3-4 systems. I have used both cpu and gpu, it is the same case.

Answer (score 0):

From the information above it's hard to tell what went wrong. Yes, debugging neural network can be very tedious. Luckily, [Tensorflow Debugger](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/debugger) is a great tool that allows you to step through the network at every iteration and analyze your weights.

Run the following command in tfdbg to get to the first `nan` or `inf` value that shows up in the graph.

```
run -f has_inf_or_nan
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure non of your labels exceeds the number-of-softmax-outputs **-1**. In such case `sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` would produce NaN instead of raising an error. Usually, this can happen if the range of your labels is 1..N, yet the softmax indices are running from 0..N-1